# R function to plot binned means and model fit, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

Sample data:

```
    pp.inc <- structure(list(has.di.rec.pp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), m.dist.km2 = c(-34.4150009155273, 6.80600023269653, -6.55499982833862, 
-61.7700004577637, 15.6840000152588, -11.2869997024536, -26.9729995727539, 
0, 81.9940032958984, -35.1459999084473, -12.5179996490479, 0, 
21.5919990539551, 81.9940032958984, -20.7770004272461, 85.9469985961914, 
-15.2959995269775, -75.5879974365234, 81.9940032958984, 3.04999995231628, 
-17.1490001678467, -25.806999206543, -16.0060005187988, -14.91100025177, 
-12.9020004272461, -16.0060005187988, 5.44000005722046, -34.4150009155273, 
81.9940032958984, 3.61400008201599, 13.7379999160767, 2.71300005912781, 
4.31300020217896), treated = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1)), .Names = c("has.di.rec.pp", "m.dist.km2", "treated"), row.names = c(NA, 
-33L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

rddplot <- function(data, outcome, runvar, treatment = treated, span, bw, ...){
    data <- data.table(data)
    data.span  <- data[abs(runvar) <= span, ]
    data.span <- data.span[ , bins := cut(runvar, 
                                          seq(-span, span, by = bw), 
                                          include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)]
    data.span.plot <- data.span[ , list(avg.outcome = mean(outcome), 
                                      avg.runvar = mean(runvar), 
                                      treated = max(treatment),
                                      n.iid = length(outcome)), keyby = bins]
    data.span.plot <- data.span.plot[ , runvar := head(seq(-span, span, by = bw), -1)]
    bp <- ggplot(data = data.span.plot, aes(x = runvar, y = avg.outcome))
    bp <- bp + geom_point(aes(colour = n.iid))
    bp <- bp + stat_smooth(data = data.span, aes(x = runvar, y = outcome,
                                                group = factor(treatment)), ...)
    bp
    return(bp)
}

rddplot(pp.inc, has.di.rec.pp, m.dist.km2, treated, 50, 5)
```

This code runs perfect if I do not wrap it in a function. I am a novice in R, only using it very infrequently. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something obvious or is it to do with `data.table` or `ggplot2`? I thought it might be something with ggplot, as other questions mention there is an issue and `aes_string` should be used. I can rewrite the `data.table` parts to use base functions. But I think the error already occurs before that, on the second line. How do I make this work?

EDIT:

[Original title:
R function returns Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'name' not found]

I had some time to look at this again and have worked out a solution, hence I also modified the title a bit. Using `eval()` didn't really work out for me, so I went the `[['columname']]` selection route. I've ditched `data.table` (and `plyr` as well), so that this only uses `base` functions except for ggplot2. I am happy for any comments on how to improve it. Please let me know if there are some essential flaws. If not I will add an answer with my solution later.

I have changed the bin calculation so that there is always a breakpoint at zero, which is necessary. Default binwidth is determined by the Silverman rule.  I am thinking of calculating model fit separately and returning it, as the model choice within ggplot is limited, however I can't think of a nice way to incorporate this for a variety of diverse models such as lm or loess, and it's not strictly necessary. I actually wanted to overlay a thin bar plot displaying the number of observations in each bin, but found out this is impossible in ggplot (I know this *generally* is a bad idea, but there are several well-published papers which use similar graphs). I don't find the `size` aestetic to appealing here, but these are really minor gripes.

Thanks for getting me on the right path.

My solution:

```
rddplot <- function(data, outcome, runvar, treatment = treated, 
                    span, bw = bw.nrd0(data[[runvar]]), ...){
    breaks <- c(sort(-seq(0, span, by = bw)[-1]), seq(0, span, by = bw))
    data.span  <- data[abs(data[[runvar]]) <= max(breaks), ]
    data.span$bins <- cut(data.span[[runvar]], breaks, 
                          include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
    data.span.plot <- as.data.frame(cbind(tapply(data.span[[outcome]], data.span$bins, mean),
                            tapply(data.span[[runvar]], data.span$bins, mean),
                            tapply(data.span[[treatment]], data.span$bins, max),
                            tapply(data.span[[outcome]], data.span$bins, length),
                            tapply(data.span[[outcome]], data.span$bins, sum)))
    colnames(data.span.plot) <- c("avg.outcome", "avg.runvar", "treated", "n.iid", "n.rec")
    data.span.plot$runvar <- head(breaks, -1)
    print(data.span.plot)
    bp <- ggplot(data = data.span.plot, aes(x = runvar, y = avg.outcome))
    bp <- bp + geom_point(aes(size = n.iid))
    bp <- bp + stat_smooth(data = data.span, aes_string(x = runvar, y = outcome,
                                                group = treatment), ...)
    print(bp)
}
```

Call:

```
rddplot(pp.inc, "has.di.rec.pp", "m.dist.km2", "treated", 50, 
        method = lm, formula = y ~ poly(x, 4, raw = TRUE))
```

Comment: You haven't given us the values of anything you called in your last line of code.  Are they supposed to be quoted names of columns?  If so, you need to explore constructing `expressions` for `data.table` to `eval`.  To make `ggplot` work inside a function you need to use `print(ggplot(...))`.  And it looks like you're plotting `x` variables that do not exist in your initial `ggplot` call and have not given us `pp.inc50` to work with either.

Comment: ...and you _will_ likely need to use `aes_string()` is your intention is to pass variables as character arguments to your function and them pass them on to ggplot.

Comment: Everything called in the last line is given in the sample data I provided, I have reformatted it with linebreaks now so it is easier to copy. The `pp.inc50` was a typo, should have been `data.span`, corrected now.

Comment: Part of the issue here is that you're just confused about symbols. `has.di.rec.pp` as a symbol only means anything in the context of the data.table `pp.inc`. Just type `has.di.rec.pp` in the console. It will tell you "object not found". So passing that symbol as an argument to your function is basically meaningless, as far as R is concerned. You probably need to make it a character, and then go the eval() and expression route as Justin mentioned.

Comment: Joran and I were discussing this quirk of `data.table`.  Often it winds up being a bigger headache than the speedup is worht. But it is also an excellent exercise in understanding the way R evaluates and parses.  The `aes_string` portion of your question remains true, you will need it unless you build your functions to output know variables. (i.e. take `runvar` instead of `runvar.name`)

Comment: argh. `runvar.name` should have been `runvar` as well, I really need to double check better next time. These were remnants from when I was experimenting with `aes_string()`. Hopefully all typos are fixed now. I will rewrite the `data.table` parts to use `base` functions or `plyr`. Since the original data is quite large, I was rather happy to make use of `data.table`.

Comment: When using `ddply()` from `plyr` or `ave()` from `base`, similar issues pop up. I guess I'll start reading up on `eval()` and how to write functions in R. Still, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably having issues with the other functions for the same reason I mentioned in my previous comment: you're trying to pass column names directly, rather than characters and then using the appropriate subsetting technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an approach using `data.table`  and some `deparse(substitute())` and `setnames` trickery....

```
rddplot <- function(data, outcome, runvar, treatment = treated, span, bw, ...){
 # convert to data.table 
 data <- data.table(data)
 # get the column names as defined in the call to rddplot 
  outname <- deparse(substitute(outcome))
  runname <- deparse(substitute(runvar))
  treatname <- deparse(substitute(treatment))
 # rename these columns with the argument namses
  setnames(data, old = c(outname,runname,treatname), new = c('outcome','runvar', 'treatment'))

  # breaks as defined in the second example
  breaks <- c(sort(-seq(0, span, by = bw)[-1]), seq(0, span, by = bw))
   # the stuff you were doing before
   data.span  <- data[abs(runvar) <= span, ]
  data.span <- data.span[ , bins := cut(runvar, 
                                        breaks, 
                                        include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)]
  data.span.plot <- data.span[ , list(avg.outcome = mean(outcome), 
                                      avg.runvar = mean(runvar), 
                                      treated = max(treatment),
                                      n.iid = length(outcome)), keyby = bins]
  # note I've removed trying to add `runvar` column to data.span.plot....)
  bp <- ggplot(data = data.span.plot, aes(x = avg.runvar, y = avg.outcome))
  bp <- bp + geom_point(aes(colour = n.iid))
  bp <- bp + stat_smooth(data = data.span, aes(x = runvar, y = outcome,
                                               group = treatment), ...)
  bp

}



rddplot(pp.inc, has.di.rec.pp, m.dist.km2, treated, 50, 5)
```

Note that if you didn't convert to data.table within the function, and assumed the data argument was a data.table, then you could use on.exit() to revert the names changed by reference.

Comment: thanks, this is a nice solution with the `deparse`/`setnames` combination. yes, the data argument typically is a `data.table`, the line was just meant to make sure of this. I realize the small sample data I've given doesn't really illustrate what I am doing, but I've tested it with my original data, works flawlessly and looks just as nice. And I guess plotting `avg.runvar` is the more elegant solution anyways. Thanks alot, accepting this.